# Running an automatic browser puppeteer on a heroku server

Tags: node.js, heroku, server, puppeteer

I'm trying to run my project on a server Part of the project is an auto-puppeteer browser and I'm running so a browser opening error is thrown
Does anyone have a solution for this?
Attaches an error

> 

/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:241
reject(new Error([
^
Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
/app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-982053/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/.../blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md
at onClose (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:241:20)
at Interface. (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:231:68)
at Interface.emit (node:events:539:35)
at Interface.close (node:readline:586:8)
at Socket.onend (node:readline:277:10)
at Socket.emit (node:events:539:35)
at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1345:12)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the Puppeteer-Heroku-Buildpack

https://github.com/jontewks/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.